# Mobile friendly navbar (no collapse)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, navbar

I have been trying to create a mobile friendly navbar that doesn't collapse.

By default the navbar collapses when the screen is shrunk to a < 768px width.

I know that this can be done by modifying bootstrap directly.
I want to avoid doing that and instead use overrides.

I stopped using navbar-header and applied the following css to stop the collapse.

```
/* stop navbar from collapsing */
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
  display: block;
}

.navbar-nav>li, .navbar-nav {
  float: left;
}

.navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child {
  margin-right: -15px;
}

.navbar-right {
  float: right;
}
```

I have it so that it doesn't collapse. However, when the screen is < 768 width, the navbar increases in height and the brand, text, button, etc. that it contains are moved slightly.

Screenshot with screen width = 768
[image]

Screenshot with screen width < 768
[image]

I created a jsbin here http://jsbin.com/vojiqi/edit?html,css,output

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to stop it?

I just want a navbar that adapts to the screen size and doesn't collapse.

**SOLUTION** 
Using bootstrap's navbar: http://jsbin.com/nemipu/edit?html,css,output 
Not using bootstrap's navbar: http://jsbin.com/pediga/edit?html,css,output

Using bootstrap's navbar (no navbar-collapse)
http://jsbin.com/posuvu/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @isherwood answer, add `border-top: 0;` to the 'navbar-collapse.collapse' class.

**Edit:** 
Assuming you want to take advantage of the Bootstrap navbar features, you could add the media query below to your CSS to stop the brand 'jumping' when the viewport changes past the breakpoint.

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {

  .navbar > .container .navbar-brand, 
  .navbar > .container-fluid .navbar-brand {
      margin-left: -15px;
  }

  .navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
  }

  .navbar-text {
    float: left;
  }

}
```

However, I would think you may want to put some space back in between the brand and the edge of the viewport.

Comment: That does get rid of the border. Thank you. But the navbar-brand still moves a lot. I'm thinking about not using navbar like isherwood suggested.

Comment: Yes, if you don't need the features of the BS navbar, it would be easier to use a container as @isherwood said.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Leo. I've updated the jsbin to show the best I could get it. I ended up with one !important that I couldn't figure out how to get rid of. This is pretty ugly honestly. http://jsbin.com/nemipu/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Okay, got rid of the !important. So this is all working with bootstrap now. Hopefully this is something they will add. http://jsbin.com/nemipu/edit?html,css,output

Comment: I also went ahead and coded this without using bootstraps navbar. My css knowledge is limited so I could be doing something not best practice. But here it is http://jsbin.com/pediga/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1):

You also have borders coming and going at that breakpoint, but this takes care of most of the problem:

```
.navbar-nav {
    margin: 0 -15px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/qifijofure/1/edit?html,css,output)**

Comment: Yes, there is still a bit of movement with the top border that is added. And the navbar-brand moves quite a bit.

Comment: The fact is that simply using a container and row and applying your color to that might be simpler than a bunch of overrides.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your code, bootstrap has a default margin in that case

```
.navbar-nav {
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: The navbar-header still moves in this case.